# Add menu options to email attachments

Tags: android, android-ndk

Please see the requirement below.

For instance, take Astro browser as a template. You might have seen context menu (with menu options such as Open as, Edit, Details and Send), popping up once an item in the list is selected. I want to implement a similar context menu, with different options, when user taps an email attachment irrespective of email clients. Ideally an option would be 'send via bluetooth', allowing the user to send the attachment straight away.

I looked for suitable APIs. However, there isn't any. This made me think about native programming. I am pretty new to those stuffs.

Could anyone throw some inputs on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help you, questions need to be much more specific. What did you read that made you think you need to do native programming? What kind of options did you want to provide? Is this your email app or that of someone else? Please edit your question and provide more information, organized into a clear objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to implement a similar context menu, with different options, when user taps an email attachment irrespective of email clients.

That is not possible, sorry. You are welcome to implement your own mail client with your own context menu, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I will develop a custom client for that.